# Get the latest version of a group of files with similar name using the get statement for download

Tags: bash, sftp, sshpass

Currently I am using the following command to download an entire directory from an SFTP server to our own. The problem is, this directory gets larger every day and most of the files in it aren't necessary. So what I do today is that I download the entire folder and then clean the unnecessary ones.

But our customer is not enjoying this solution because it leads to heavy file transfers (which they are paying for).

The current version:

```
sshpass -p $FTP_PASS sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss [USERNAME]@[SFTP_DOMAIN].com <<EOF

get -r Export
EOF
```

I'd like to improve on this script so that instead of downloading the entire folder, the script searches for files that start with a specific string and only then get the latest version of them.

E.g.

We are looking for the latest versions of the ones that start with either `Subscribers_Extracts` or `Clicks` or `Account_Extract` and we have the following list in the directory:

```
Subscribers_Extracts_1.csv 
Subscribers_Extracts_2.csv
Subscribers_Extracts_3.csv
Subscribers_Extracts_4.csv (latest modified)
Clicks_ftyftyf.csv
Clicks_67546754675.csv (latest modified)
Clicks_783635ghgh.csv 
Account_Extract_uguyfuyfuf.csv
```

Then the files we should download are going be

```
Subscribers_Extracts_4.csv
Clicks_67546754675.csv
Account_Extract.csv
```

Note that we picked the files based on the Modified date and not the numbers on their names.

Also note that the last type aka `Account_Extract.csv` is the only file matching the third pattern so we receive that regardless of its modified date.

How can I save my customer a lot of data transfer?

Comment: If you are always copying from the same source to the same destination, it may be worth switching to [`rsync`](https://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/538767/how-to-rsync-files-folders-from-a-specific-date-forward

Comment: but does `rsync` work on SSHPASS and SFTP servers?

Comment: do you have access to an ssh shell or only sftp through sshpass?

Answer (score 0):

rsync can sync files modified on the last given amount of time, but for something more flexible you can check the last modification date (in seconds) of a file with:

`date +%s -r filename`

Then implement the check in a loop for each filename root (i.e. checking for every `f in Subscribers_Extract*`), saving the filename for which the date is higher.

However `date -r` doesn't work on OS X systems.

EDITED

If you can ssh into the remote server and execute bash script, this gives the name of the latest "Subscribers_..." modified, which you can copy:

```
#!/bin/bash
list="$( ls Subscribers_Extract* )"
names=( $list )
nr_names=${#names[@]}
date_modify=0
file_to_copy="none"
for i in `seq 0 $(( nr_names - 1 ))` 
do date_tmp=`date +%s -r ${names[$i]}`
if (( $date_tmp>$date_modify ))
then
date_modify=$date_tmp
file_to_copy=${names[$i]}
fi
done
echo $file_to_copy
```

Comment: it's an Ubuntu. can you help me with the code on the example I gave above?

Comment: Can you use ssh shell?

Comment: i only have access to the Ubuntu shell via PuTTY.